# As soon as it’s done?

Tags: sentence-construction

The questionable sentence is the following:

> We are setting up a server and as soon as it’s done we will send you the bucket credentials.

Shall I use “ when it’s done” or “as soon as it’s done is OK? Or none of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**We can use either phrase in this sentence.** Either phrase would be correct, understandable, and sound natural.

**If we want to emphasize urgency, we may want to use "as soon as" instead of "when".** "When" here means that the speaker will send the credentials *near* the time after the server is set up. "As soon as" indicates that the speaker will send the credentials *immediately after* the server is set up.